# how to run two programs in java such that one runs infinitely and the other on button click

Tags: java, netbeans

I got a jframe and want to run two program at once. one program runs when a button is clicked and the other in background infinitely. How can i achieve this. Button click shouldn't stop the other program.

Comment: You can use threads actually can multithreading a thread with just a start() and the other would via button but with also with a start() method!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **multithreading functionality** of java.The Program or Piece of code that you want to run indefinitely put it in a separate Thread and Add a Event Listener to Button so that button click code will run in main thread and other code will run indefinitely until the main thread is stop or program is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Junaid and userXXXX it's the best idea to use threads for this. You might want to have a look on the threading section from your Java tutorial (you should have one!!!). You can also set your threads to be a "deamon" thread, so they won't block your program from closing.